# Sharepoint Search, ignore a list column from searching

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search, crawling, crawl-rules

I've created a custom search, using scopes.
There is smth, that I don't want the search to index a specific column of a list.
How can I ignore this column from being searched

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should set the NoCrawl Property to true of the column.

[SPField.NoCrawl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfield.nocrawl.aspx)

Comment: I have another question. How can I do that using administration panel?

Comment: administration panel? did you mean Central Admin ? go to search service app, on left navgation panel, click "managed properties", click "crawled properties" and type your column name then click search,  make sure your column is not mapped to any Managed Properties  and not include in index

Comment: No `managed properties` found in SP2013 under `Search Service Application`.